# How to remove a part of filename?

Tags: file-rename

I would like to remove 'out_' at the beginning of files.
I tried:

```
get-childitem out_doe*.asc | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("out_", "") }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('


rename "out_*.asc" "////*.asc"
syntax error at (user-supplied code), near "*."
```

Thank you

How to do that in bash?

Comment: You have a strange issue with your post. You posted Powershell code, but a bash syntax error. It's unclear what you're trying to do, unless you're attempting to use that Powershell code at a bash command prompt or bash script (which clearly won't work).

Comment: How to use Powershell please? I give this codes to terminal

Comment: Powershell is part of Windows. This isn't a tutorial site, I'm afraid. If you're running Windows. use your favorite search engine to find a Powershell tutorial or article on the Microsoft site.

Comment: I am on linux mint

Comment: Then you're not going to be able to use that Powershell code, and you'll have to search this site for a bash-related solution to your problem. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much